# How can I advertise on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, advertising

I can see the advertisements on Stack Overflow. If I wish to advertise my banners.

- Where should I contact?
- What is the procedure?
- Can I place my advertisement for a specific tag?
- What is the pricing?

Answer (score 21):

Click on the [Advertising info link](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) to contact Stack Exchange

[image]

Comment: This is also covered in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/advertising).

Answer (score 9):

Additionally, the [FAQ covers this](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

> ### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and
>   tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant
>   answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or
>   website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your
>   answers.
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product
>   or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our
>   advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for
>   details. We also offer free community promotion ads for open source
>   projects and non-profit organizations.